# Solve x for a quadratic equation (not finding zeroes)

Tags: quadratics

With a linear function $f(x)=5x+2=q$ 
can be solved for $x$ by rewriting it as
$x=(q-2)/5$ 
While with a quadratic function 
$f(x)=5x^2+2x+2=q$ how would you solve for both x's on one side?
So you clearly can not add the solutions for $5x^2=q$ and $2x+2=q$.
Is there an equation to relate y values of $5x^2=$(some relation of q) and $2x+2=$(some relation of q) to q?

Comment: You can subtract $q$ from both sides to get $5x^2+2x+(2-q) = 0$, and then use the quadratic formula. Is that what you want, or are you looking for something else?

Comment: No Im not trying to find zeros of the function which would happen if I follow through with the quadratic formula. I'm trying to find an expression that uses y values as a x acting variable to be equivalent to any x value of that fuction

Comment: as there are two solutions in general, you can't solve for $x$ in the sense $x=f(q)$ for some real valued function $f$. the best you get is the quadratic formula. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula

Comment: So the only possible solutions are when x is 0 and can not be determined for any other value

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea is quite exceptional. It is not generally adopted because the values of x in a quadratic equation can readily be found by methods like factorization, completing square and as well as quadratic formula.

Your suggestion is to break the original into P: 2x + 2 = k and Q : 5x^2 = q – k and hope that the k (if can easily be found) can help in solving the equation with lesser effort. Let see if that is possible or not.

By eliminating x from P and Q, we end up with $5k^2 – 16k + (20 – 4q) = 0$.

Of course, the value(s) of k can be found but we need to **solve another quadratic**! The worst thing has yet to be come – extraneous value of k must be distinguished and be discarded.

The following uses q = 5 as an example:-

By ‘normal’ methods, we found x = –1 or 3/5.

Using your approach, we have … k = 0 or 16/5.

When k = 0, from P, we get x = –1, but from Q, we get x =–1 or 1(has to be rejected)

When k = 16/5, from P, x = 3/5, but from Q, we get x = 3/5 or –3/5 (has to be rejected)

Note also that the above is just an exceptionally simple example. That means not every quadratic in k has integral/fractional/real roots.

Summing up:- Your approach is a possible way to solve a quadratic but time is wasted in doing many extra work.

Answer (score 0):

So you are asking us to find two convenient functions $f,g$ such that$$5x^2=f(q),\\2x+2=g(q),$$ which are related by $$f(q)+g(q)=q.$$

Obviously, we can eliminate $g(q):=q-f(q)$, and

$$5x^2=f(q),\\2x+2=q-f(q).$$

This system is compatible iff

$$\frac{f(q)}5=\left(\frac{q-f(q)-2}2\right)^2.$$

The solution of this quadratic equation are

$$f(q)=q\pm2\sqrt{\frac q5-\frac9{25}}-\frac85,$$
implying
$$g(q)=\mp2\sqrt{\frac q5-\frac9{25}}+\frac85.$$

So yes, it is possible to find these functions, they are well defined, but they don't help making things simpler, on the opposite.

---

The way that works is by completing the square
$$5x^2+2x+2=5(x+\frac15)^2+2-5\left(\frac15\right)^2=q,$$
then
$$\left(x+\frac15\right)^2=\frac q5-\frac9{25}.$$